# Rsyslog output to Kafka Timing Out

Tags: rsyslog, kafka

I'm having trouble setting up Rsyslog output to Kafka using the omkafka module.  I have a robust Kafka cluster running in a production environment.  In the current workflow, Rsyslog receives events on UDP:514 and writes them to file.  Filebeat reads several files, pre-processes, and ships to different topics in Kafka.  This process is working as intended, but I'd like to streamline and have Rsyslog send straight to Kafka.  I made a few attempts to get this working on a test device in the existing environment with no success.  To simplify, I've created a fresh VM with default installations of OS, Kafka, and Rsyslog and am not able to send Rsyslog -> Kafka on that VM either.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't see it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some additional details:

==== OS and Application Versions ====

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.8 (Ootpa)"

java -version
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.21.0.9-1) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.21.0.9-1) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
3.6.0

rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd  8.2310.0 (aka 2023.10) compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        systemd support:                        Yes
        Config file:                            /etc/rsyslog.conf
        PID file:                               /var/run/syslogd.pid
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

==== KAFKA ====

The Kafka install is using 100% default settings from the quickstart instructions here for the KRaft version: [Apache Kafka Quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).  Kafka is listening on localhost:9092.

```
$ netstat -ntlp | grep 9092
tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*                    LISTEN      7187/java
```

I have tested and can send and receive events using the built-in producer and consumer scripts as follows:

```
$ /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test
Created topic test.

$ /kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
This is a kafka test sent from the kafka console producer

$ /kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
This is a kafka test sent from the kafka console producer
```

==== RSYSLOG ====

The Rsyslog install uses the default settings.  I've installed a few dependencies that I believe are used by the Rsyslog omkafka module:

```
$ yum list installed | grep kafka
librdkafka.x86_64                             0.11.4-3.el8                              @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
rsyslog-kafka.x86_64                          8.2310.0-1.el8                            @rsyslog_v8
```

I'm using the following bare-bones config to send test events to Kafka.  It also writes them to file to confirm they've been generated correctly.

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/kafka-sender.conf

module(load="omkafka") 

if $msg contains "kafka-test" then {

    action(
            type="omkafka"
            broker=["localhost:9092"]
            topic="test"
            errorFile="/var/log/remote-hosts/errors_kafka.log"
      )

    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/remote-hosts/kafka.log")
}
```

I'm now generating test events.  The events are recorded into kafka.log as expected, meaning that Rsyslog is picking them up and filtering properly, but none of the events are received on Kafka.

```
$ logger
kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka
kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka 2

$ cat /var/log/remote-hosts/kafka.log
Oct 30 05:55:20 localhost anthony[76955]: kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost anthony[76955]: kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka 2
```

The events seem to be queued and are not written to the error log until I restart rsyslog:

```
$ cat /var/log/remote-hosts/errors_kafka.log
{ "errcode": -152, "errmsg": "Local: Purged in queue", "data": "2023-10-30T05:55:20.506080-04:00 localhost anthony[76955]: kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka\n" }
{ "errcode": -152, "errmsg": "Local: Purged in queue", "data": "2023-10-30T05:55:23.275050-04:00 localhost anthony[76955]: kafka-test This is a test message to send from rsyslog to kafka 2\n" }
```

I've checked in the rsyslog journal and have some errors, but haven't been able to find much info about these errors online.  It's obviously not able to connect to Kafka.

```
Oct 30 05:54:43 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: imjournal: journal files changed, reloading...  [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: omkafka: action will suspended due to kafka error -195: Local: Broker transport failure [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: omkafka: action will suspended due to kafka error -187: Local: All broker connections are down [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: omkafka: action will suspended due to kafka error -195: Local: Broker transport failure [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: omkafka: action will suspended due to kafka error -195: Local: Broker transport failure [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
Oct 30 05:55:23 localhost.localdomain rsyslogd[76655]: action 'action-0-omkafka' suspended (module 'omkafka'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2310.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

I am out of ideas.  Does anyone have a suggestion?  Happy to provide more information if need.

Thanks in advance.

-Anthony